# Perl regex match array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I'm pretty bad with regex, and tried searching on google, but everything I tried didn't worked.

Here's my code :

```
@liner = split(/\s+/, $_);
foreach my $v (@liner) {
    if ($v =~ /*.duplex.*/) {
        print ECRIRE ";$v";
    }
}
```

$v contains something like : "Full-duplex," but can contains other things like "Half-duplex,"....

So I want my condition to match on "any char"duplex"any char".

I tried things like `if ($v =~ /(*.)duplex(.*)/)`

And some others, but not working. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The first `*.` is invalid - it need's to be `.*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (split(/\s+/)) {
    print ECRIRE ";$_" if /duplex/i;
}
```

Luckily, in Perl RegEx are not matched against a whole string, meaning that you don't have to prefix and postfix everything with ".*":

```
/abcd/
```

is synonymous to

```
/.*abcd.*/
```

(unless you're using a specific option which adds newlines to the matching chars for the dot)

This loop matches on everything duplex in all cases (the /i makes the RegEx case-insensitive).

(Untested, but fingers are crossed)

Comment: Oh god... What a noob i am... Thanks dude for explanations !

Comment: That doesn't even compile

Answer (score -1):

The [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) module has a `firstval` function, which will return the first value in a list that satisfies a certain constraint. It is very useful for writing concise and readable code. It is not a core module and you may need to install it.

As others have said, all you need in your regex is `/duplex/`, as that will check that the string *contains* the string. You can enhance it with `/duplex/i` which performs a case-insensitive match instead.

Finally, if you are writing `split /\s+/` then you almost certainly want `split ' '` instead; that is a literal single-space *string*, not a regex, and it is the *default* for `split` if you don't provide the first parameter. The difference is that, if the target string *starts* with whitespace then spltting with `/\s+/` will return an empty string as the first element of the list, whereas with `' '` it will return just the non-space characters. If you pass no parameters at all to `split` then it is equivalent to `split ' ', $_` which is often what you want.

This short program demonstrates these points.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'firstval';

$_ = 'simplex full-duplex half-duplex';

print firstval { /duplex/ } split;
```

**output**

```
full-duplex
```